# Connect Internet through two different LAN Interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I am trying to connect an IoT device to internet. It is running on Ubuntu.

It has two Ethernet interfaces. One is connected to a LTE modem + antenna (fast and cheap connection), and the other is connected to a Satellite modem + antenna (can connect everywhere, expensive and unreliable).

I have two types of message to send to my server:

- An alarm, if any problem occurs on the device, that I want to send
  through Satellite, at anytime.
- All the data when an LTE connection is available.

Most of the time no LTE connection is available.

Is there anyway I could program this networking strategy?

I thought about alternating between the interfaces with `ifup` and `ifdown`, but I don't want the data message to be interrupted by the alarm message and vice-versa.

I appreciate any solution or idea. Since the project is mostly written in python it would be awesome if there is a library solution that exists, but I am open to anything.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the output of `ip -o a` please?

Comment: @darth_epoxy I don't have the hardware yet, but I can forecast it will look something like this:


`2: enx4865ee1425f9    inet 192.168.1.67/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx4865ee1425f9\       valid_lft 85425sec preferred_lft 85425sec`
`3: enx4865ee1425f1    inet 192.168.2.32/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx4865ee1425f1\       valid_lft 85425sec preferred_lft 85425sec`

Comment: If it picks up 2 separate ethernets (entries starting with en) then you should be use and sqitch between them. your question is more of a unix network question rather than Ubuntu but if you are lucky a guru might read this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with static routes, where you send over certain interface. You just have to make sure that the destination has a valid backroute so that all trafic that goes out over one interface will also get its answer on the same interface.